# How does C# crypto libraries handle keys that are smaller than the key size required by the encryption algorithm?

Tags: c#, node.js

Let's use as an example the TripesDES algorithm which requires a 192bit key.
How does C# handle a smaller key? Let's say 128 bits key (see example below)

In nodejs attempting to use a smaller key will throw an "Invalid key size" error. C# continues and outputs the encryption. I guess some type of padding is used internally? If that's case, which padding? I think `PKCS7` is only used to padd every encryption block, am I right? It doesn't relate to the encryption key itself.

```
    var cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    {
        Key = new byte[]
        {
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA,
            0xAA
        },
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    };
    var encryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor();
    var token = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: You can have a look at the source code of it at https://referencesource.microsoft.com

Comment: "This algorithm supports key lengths from 128 bits to 192 bits in increments of 64 bits." - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key(v=vs.110).aspx). Did you try with less than 128 bits? That should raise an CryptographicException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's use as an example the TripesDES algorithm which requires a
>   192bit key

that's not exactly correct. TripleDES basically applies DES 3 times with 3 keys. Those 3 keys can be:

- all equal. That's regular DES. We can ignore that option
- all different. This is what you expect, 192bit key (3 keys combined)
- 2 keys are the same, 3rd is different. Weaker than when all keys are different, but still stronger than regular DES. This gives us 128bit key (2 keys combined).

.NET implementation supports last 2 options, so when you use 128bit key(like you do in your question) - it will split it into 2 keys and use one of them (first) as 3rd key, so in result you will have 1 and 3rd keys the same.

Note that .NET will verify your key to be not "weak" triple DES key, so for the example in your question it will throw exception, because both left half and right half of your key are the same, which, given above, will result in encryption with 3 identical keys, so the whole thing will reduce to regular DES.

In general, .NET verifies if keys you pass are of legal size for given algorithm.

You can verify the above by first encrypting with some 16-byte key:

```
var key = new byte[] {
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0xAA,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00
};
```

And then manually append first 8 bytes to the end to get 24-byte key:

```
var fullKey = key.Concat(key.Take(8)).ToArray()
```

And decrypt with it (it will decrypt just fine, because both 16-byte and 24-byte keys are identical as per above).

Comment: Awesome, now I understand what's going on behind the scenes. As I said I was using a 16 byte key in my C# program to encrypt some data using 3DES ECB algorithm (pkcs7 padding). To obtain the same output I need to clone the first 8 bytes of my 16 byte key and append it to the bottom producing the 24 byte key that you are talking about. Thank you @Evk

Comment: You are welcome. Note that better way would be to use 24byte key right away in C#, since 16 byte one is weaker. But if you have some key length restrictments - why not. Also not sure what you mean by "append to the bottom" :) I hope that means to the end (and not prepend at the beginning).

Comment: In this case I need to use the weaker version. And by "bottom" I mean to end ;)

Answer (score 0):

> the TripesDES algorithm [which] requires a 192bit key.

TripleDES provides multiple options for the key size (128 or 192 bits).
*Refs*: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES), [StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24664/key-sizes-supported-by-3des)

And so does the [TripleDES-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This algorithm supports key lengths from 128 bits to 192 bits in
>   increments of 64 bits. -[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key(v=vs.110).aspx)

If your provide a key with an invalid lenght, a CryptographicException gets thrown.

All algorithms which inherit from [SymmetricAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) work this way (e.g.
[AES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx), [DES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.des(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Thank you for the help Hyarus ;)